# PyQt binding current instance of 'self' to imported UI 'self'

Tags: qt, python-3.x, autocomplete, pyqt

Sorry if there is more correct jargon for what I am trying to convey in the subject line.

lets say i use `pyuic` on a `.ui` file generated by Qt 4 Designer and save it as `gui.py`. Since I shouldn't modify the file as noted in the header by **# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!**, in another source file I import the `Ui_MainWindow` from `gui.py` with `from gui import Ui_MainWindow`. I subclass `QMainWindow` and set the `ui` to the main window from the `gui.py` with `self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()` and set it up with `self.setupUi(self)`. My problem is that the auto-complete now doesn't recognize the variables from `gui.py` in the current file.

How would I set up the editor so when I type `self` for the results to populate respectively.

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("qt_designed_ui.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # bind this subclassed code based UI to the actual UI made with Qt Designer 4
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

with the above, something like `self.ui.var` will provide introspection for `var`, but it's an illegal statement. I must use `self.var`, which is legal but does not provide introspection. Furthermore, I know `self.var` works because the entire application works and I address many attributes of the class with that form, I'm just lacking the introspection on PyCharm.

Comment: Are you saying the PyCharm does not apply proper introspection on `self.ui`?

Comment: @Crispin No, self within my subclass of `QMainWindow`, which initializes it's ui with the contents from `gui.py` generated by `pyuic`. Addressing a variable with a `self.ui` prefix doesn't work, I have to use only `self`, which provides no introspection. Oddly though, it does provide the introspection for `self.ui`.

Comment: I am confused. Perhaps some sample code would help. The standard convention is to subclass `QMainWindow` and set `self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()`. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: @Crispin I've added the code that I'm using.

Comment: super(MyWindowClass).__init__(parent) ?

Comment: @Achayan that throws `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer a single inheritance approach:

```
from gui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Introspection on the `Ui_MainWindow` via `self.ui` and on `QMainWindow` via `self` are both available:

[image]

[image]

UI components are members of the `Ui_MainWindow` instance, so they are accessed through `self.ui`:

```
self.text_save = self.ui.txt_save
```

Comment: If I change `self.setupUi(self)` to `self.ui.setupUi(self)` I get `AttributeError: 'MyWindowClass' object has no attribute 'txt_save'` with both single and multiple inheritance. Single inheritance with the my original `setupUi()` throws `AttributeError: 'MyWindowClass' object has no attribute 'setupUi'`. After testing this, I think it might be related to the multiple inheritance using `uic`

Comment: Create `gui.py` using the command: `pyuic4 qt_designed_ui.ui > gui.py`

Comment: I had that too. I was originally using it with the multiple inheritance. I had just forgotten about it when I posted my code before.

Comment: Why don't you post what `gui.py` looks like after you run that command?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand more now. Inheriting from `form_class` which is `<class 'Ui_MainWindow'>` is why it allows me to do `self.var` legally, but it doesn't provide introspection I suppose because the variables aren't in the scope until runtime or something maybe. And then it starts to look for the variables in external scopes If I remember correctly. Regardless, it seems like my problem is solved after changing it to be like yours is just changing all of the `self.var` instances to `self.ui.var` and using it that way. Thanks Crispin.